# JHipster & Gradle: Running Junit tests from STS

Tags: spring, eclipse, gradle, junit, jhipster

I have a jhipster 4.6.2 application with gradle build. There is a problem with running tests from IDE. Tests are executed normally from command line but running tests fails from STS by clicking `Run As Junit Test` fails for application context failure:

```
            ??? ???   ??? ????????? ????????   ??????? ????????? ????????? ????????
            ??? ???   ??? ????????? ????????? ???????? ????????? ????????? ?????????
            ??? ?????????    ???    ????????? ???????     ???    ???????   ?????????
      ???   ??? ?????????    ???    ????????   ???????    ???    ???????   ????????
      ????????? ???   ??? ????????? ???       ????????    ???    ????????? ???  ????
       ???????  ???   ??? ????????? ???       ???????     ???    ????????? ???   ???

    :: JHipster ?  :: Running Spring Boot 1.5.4.RELEASE ::
    :: https://jhipster.github.io ::

    2017-08-02 12:10:17.366  INFO 13116 --- [           main] c.k.v.web.rest.PainResourceIntTest       : Starting PainResourceIntTest on DESKTOP-497IN2I with PID 13116 (started by mikke in C:\Projects\testApp)
    2017-08-02 12:10:17.371  INFO 13116 --- [           main] c.k.v.web.rest.PainResourceIntTest       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
    2017-08-02 12:10:23.260  WARN 13116 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000014: Found use of deprecated [org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator] sequence-based id generator; use org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator instead.  See Hibernate Domain Model Mapping Guide for details.
    2017-08-02 12:10:23.263  WARN 13116 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000014: Found use of deprecated [org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator] sequence-based id generator; use org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator instead.  See Hibernate Domain Model Mapping Guide for details.
    2017-08-02 12:10:23.264  WARN 13116 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000014: Found use of deprecated [org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator] sequence-based id generator; use org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator instead.  See Hibernate Domain Model Mapping Guide for details.
    2017-08-02 12:10:23.264  WARN 13116 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000014: Found use of deprecated [org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator] sequence-based id generator; use org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator instead.  See Hibernate Domain Model Mapping Guide for details.
    2017-08-02 12:10:23.264  WARN 13116 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000014: Found use of deprecated [org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator] sequence-based id generator; use org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator instead.  See Hibernate Domain Model Mapping Guide for details.
    2017-08-02 12:10:23.442  WARN 13116 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    2017-08-02 12:10:23.467 ERROR 13116 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:967)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
        ... 40 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level cache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath.
        at org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory.buildEntityRegion(NoCachingRegionFactory.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory.buildEntityRegion(RegionFactory.java:132)
        at org.hibernate.internal.CacheImpl.determineEntityRegionAccessStrategy(CacheImpl.java:439)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:120)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:297)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:445)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889)
        ... 46 common frames omitted

    2017-08-02 12:10:23.470 ERROR 13116 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@2723b0d0] to prepare test instance [com.company.testApp.web.rest.PainResourceIntTest@7137cd14]

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
        ... 25 common frames omitted
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:967)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
        ... 40 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheRegionFactoryAvailableException: Second-level cache is used in the application, but property hibernate.cache.region.factory_class is not given; please either disable second level cache or set correct region factory using the hibernate.cache.region.factory_class setting and make sure the second level cache provider (hibernate-infinispan, e.g.) is available on the classpath.
        at org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory.buildEntityRegion(NoCachingRegionFactory.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory.buildEntityRegion(RegionFactory.java:132)
        at org.hibernate.internal.CacheImpl.determineEntityRegionAccessStrategy(CacheImpl.java:439)
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:120)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:297)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:445)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889)
        ... 46 common frames omitted
```

I have followed instructions from 
https://jhipster.github.io/configuring-ide-eclipse-gradle/
and I can run the application itself from STS.

I guess the problem has something to do with application.yml, but I don't know how to use it for tests.

Comment: did you ever find a fix to this?  Still occurs in 2020

Comment: @RobShepherd see the accepted answer. Is there not enough information for you? Nowadays I'm using IntelliJ and haven't had such problems

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Run as JUnit test" uses the default JUnit runner so any custom test setup logic in your gradle build won't be fired. I suggest you use the [Buildship eclipse plugin](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship) and use "run as gradle test".

Another option is to use a JUnit concept for custom test setup so it's fired in gradle and the IDE eg a `TestSuite`, `@RunWith` or a `@Rule`

Comment: If I create Jhipster application with maven as a build tool running the tests work with "Run as JUnit test". Why would it be different with gradle?

Comment: Please include the full stack trace. I can't see the cause of the `Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory` exception. How did you load the project into eclipse? Possibly there's something screwy with the eclipse classpath. If you're not using `Buildship` then you'll need to apply the [eclipse plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html) to your gradle build and run the `eclipseClasspath` task

Comment: Edited the question by adding the full stack trace. I used buildship to load the project.

Comment: Looks like `hibernate.cache.region.factory_class` property is not specified in the hibernate config. Do you have two versions of the hibernate config file on the classpath? If so you might find that gradle's classpath ordering is different to eclipse's classpath ordering so you might find one config file "winning" in gradle and another "winning" in eclipse. Ideally you should NEVER rely on classpath ordering. Every resource on the classpath should have a unique "path"

Comment: yes, modifying the build path order I can get tests working i.e. prioritizing test/resources over main/resources. Of course then running the application fails.

Comment: Unfortunately eclipse has a single classpath, it doesn't have one for test and another for runtime like gradle. So it's always a square peg in a round hole. I suggest you don't rely on classpath ordering, perhaps you could use a system property to choose between the two config files (each with a unique path)